# Edit and Continue with UWP JS?

Tags: javascript, uwp, edit-and-continue

Is Edit and Continue feature available in UWP JavaScript at Visual Studio Community 2017 ?

Like editing the HTML file (or .js maybe?) and instantly seeing the changes visually?